# Uses Permission in manifest cannot be accessble

Tags: android-studio, android-manifest

I write uses permission on my android studio.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" android:maxSdkVersion="34" android:minSdkVersion="24"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="34" android:minSdkVersion="24"/>
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Myproject"
        tools:targetApi="31">

//my activities
 </application>

</manifest>
```

I am implementing an image button that have an MIC image, that if click user can speak it and save then display that voice speech but upon working with clickng that imge button,I encounter some problem.

```
//ReceiverActivity3
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  //existing codes
    imageViewSpeakBtn = findViewById(R.id.imageView_speakbtn);
    imageViewSpeakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
        if (!isRecording) {
          if (checkPermissions()) {
            startRecording();
          } else {
            requestPermissions();
          }
        } else {
          stopRecording();
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

```
// example function
private void requestPermissions() {
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
    this,
    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
    PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE
  );
}
```

```
//build.gradle(:app)
android{

 namespace 'com.example.Myproj'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example..Myproj"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }
}
```

The error is :
Cannot resolve symbol 'RECORD_AUDIO'
Cannot resolve symbol 'WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'

Comment: Make sure that you have specified the correct version for `minSdkVersion`, `compileSdkVersion`, and `targetSdkVersion` according to your SDK.

Comment: I have commented line in my codes
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"  android:maxSdkVersion="34" />
is it not correct?

Comment: Drop your project's manifest file and (:app) build.gradle file into your question description please.

Comment: @helloFriend I think you have not implemented it properly or added half of the code here. Add complete code of requesting permission or make sure that you implemented proper code with `ActivityResult()` method.

Comment: @harsh panchal, already edited now.

Answer (score 0):

Due to some research.
In my

`private void requestPermissions(){}`
if I type `Manifest.permission.` after inputting dot "." after word permission no intenseness will show up because in the import I did not include this->

`import android.Manifest;`